# Implement a customized Google Calendar with React Js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar, google-calendar-api, react-big-calendar

My website currently runs a `react-big-calendar` `Calendar` with data I manually manage with **graphql** / **Apollo**

I decided to use **Google Calendar** for data management using the **Google Calendar API** instead of managing everything on my own database.

However, I was wondering if there was a way to directly include a *custom* **Google Calendar** ( the UI I mean ) in my website, so the Front-End part would be also managed by **Google Calendar** ( can be in an iframe, or a Google Component directly, if such a thing exists ).

This way I would leave most of the calendar front/back end logic to Google only, instead of having to call the Google API everytime I do a change on my `react-big-calendar`.

I say custom, because I would still need to edit some component, such as the pop-up opening when you want to create an event:

[image]

Most of the information have no use for me, and I would like to add others. I would also like to get rid of "*search for people*" or the create button on the sidebar, as an exemple.

Is there a way to include such a customized **Google Calendar** in my website? Or do I need to keep using my own `react-big-calendar` with data from the **Google Calendar API**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is [this](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en) of help to you?

Comment: @ale13 sadly not, as an iframe won't provide the capacity to edit the calendar content (not the event but other components such as sidebar ) or to customize the create event pop up

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately what you want cannot be achieved as Calendar doesn’t offer the possibility of editing/modifying any of its content.

Hence, the only available options in this situation are:

- to embed it as explained in this article [here](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/41207?hl=en);
- make use of the Calendar API and build your own interface for it, just like you mentioned above.

Comment: You confirm my first thought. Thanks. Hopefully they provide this feature on the future.